# Mod 2 is primitive recursive

Tags: computability, primitive-recursion

> Given a function E(x) which outputs 0 is x is even and 1 is x is odd, prove that this function is primitive recursive.

---

My attempt is as follows

$$ E(x) = x \mod 2$$
To show that any function is primitive recursive, it must be obtained by composition and recursion from the initial functions $s(x) = x + 1; n(x) = 0$ and $u_i^n(x_1,x_2 \ldots x_n) = x_i$
We know that 
$$ E(0) = 0 $$
$$ E(x+1) = (E(x) + 1) \mod 2 $$
By using induction -
$$ E(n) = n \mod 2$$
Let $n = 0$
$$ E(0) = 0$$
which is easily shown to be primitive recursive since it is an initial function of the $PRC$ class.
Assuming that this is true for $n = k$.
$$E(k) = k \mod 2$$
Taking $ n = k+1 $
$$ E(k+1) = (E(k) + 1)\mod 2 $$

But at this point, I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: I'll give you two hints. (1) When you said "by using induction" what is the precise statement you proved by induction? It is *not* "$E$ is primitive recursive". (2) Why did you not simply write down the primitive recursive construction of $E$? You should make a definition of $E$ using only $s$, $n$, $u_i^n$, but in your attempt I see no such thing. It should start with "$E(x) = \cdots$" where $\cdots$ mentions only $E$, $s$, $n$, $u_i^n$ and previously defined primitive recursive functions.

Comment: (2) I don't know what the primitive construction of $ E(x) $.  (1) I thought that if $E(0)$ is primitive recursive and E(k + 1) is proven to be primitive recursive then $E(x)$ will be primitive recursive by induction principle.

Comment: It is meaningless to say "$E(0)$ is primitive recursive" You can only say "$E$ is primitive recursive." Primitive recursiveness is a property of *functions*, and not of their values. You do not understand the definition of primitive recursive, it seems. You should first try to demonstrate that $f(x) = x + 3$ is primitive recursive, to make sure you understand the definition.

Comment: Maybe an example will help. Define $f(x,y) = x + 2$. Then we can prove that $f$ is primitve recursive as follows: $f$ is primitive recursive because $f = s \circ s \circ u_1^2$, or written a bit less mysteriously, because $f(x,y) = s(s(u_1^2(x,y)))$ for all $x, y$. This is the sort of proof you need to do. Induction might help *after* you have written $E$ using only the building blocks for primitive recursive functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function $a(x)$ by primitive recursion as follows: $a(0) = s(0)$ and $a(x+1) = 0$. In particular, this function satisfies $a(0) = 1$ and $a(1) = 0$. Now we can define $E(x)$ by primitive recursion: $E(0) = 0$ and $E(x+1) = a(E(x))$. You can prove that $E(x)$ works by induction (left to you).